# If String ONLY contains "-" or "."

Tags: python, user-input, morse-code

I'm writing a small function which checks to see if an inputted string is morse code.
The function should do something like 
"If "-" or "." only in Inputted_string: "
But i can't seem to find a way to do the only bit on Python3.
The current way i have this implemented is **very** messy and not very Pythonic

```
if "-" in message:
    # message might be morse code so check even more
        if "." in message:
            # Message IS morse code so return true
            return True
        else:
            # TODO you can use a REGEX for the below things
            if '--' in message:
                # if the messsage contains only hyphens, then check to see if
                # message contans hyphen only morse code by checking all hyphen
                # only morse code against message
                return True
            elif '-----' in message:
                # if message contains 0 in morse code, return True
                return True
    if "." in message:
        # message might contain morse code
        if "-" in message:
            # message IS morse code.
            return True
        else:
            # check to see if message is dots only morse code
            # TODO you can use a REGEX for the below things
            if ".." in message:
                # message IS Morse Code
                return True
            elif "..." in message:
                # message IS Morse Code
                return True
            elif "....":
            # message IS Morse Code
                return True
        # if dots or dash not in message, return none
        return("Message has no hyphens or full stops")
```

the formatting is slightly off when i pasted, but that's the general gist. 
When it checks to see if message is "----" or ".." etc, this is because some morse code letters are only those charecters, but i'm sure there's a much easier way to go around this!

Comment: `return all(char in {'.', '-', ' '} for char in message)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - why a list and not a string? `all(char in '.- ' for char in message)`

Comment: @Robᵩ it's not a list, it's a set, so lookup is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`

Comment: Thanks. Old eyes mistook the curly braces for square braces.

Comment: @Brandon Skerritt Just to be sure: are you really checking only for a single Morse code symbol? (I'm asking because you left out the space char)

Comment: "*checks to see if an inputted string is morse code*" - Excuse me, I'd just like to interject for a moment; Morse is a code where the long signals have three times the duration of the short signals, and your dits and dahs take the same number of bytes and same screen width as each other blah blah blah etc. etc. By the way, if it matters, you have a bug in your code with `elif "....":` which should probably say `elif "...." in message:`. Just testing `if "astring"` will always be True. Strings with content test as True, empty strings test as False.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def is_morse(message):
    allowed = {".", "-", " "}
    return allowed.issuperset(message)
```

But because the message has all the characters does not mean it is valid. You would need to check if each is valid which you can do using a dict mapping letters to morse, you also need to have some format which is unambiguous i.e a space between letters and 2 or more spaces between words:

```
morse = {'---': 'O', '--.': 'G', '-...': 'B', '-..-': 'X', '.-.': 'R', '--.-': 'Q',
         '--..': 'Z', '.--': 'W', '..---': '2', '.-': 'A', '..': 'I', '-.-.': 'C',
         '..-.': 'F', '-.--': 'Y', '-': 'T', '.': 'E', '.-..': 'L', '...': 'S',
         '..-': 'U', '.----': '1', '-----': '0', '-.-': 'K', '-..': 'D', '----.':
             '9', '-....': '6', '.---': 'J', '.--.': 'P', '....-': '4', '--': 'M',
         '-.': 'N', '....': 'H', '---..': '8', '...-': 'V', '--...': '7', '.....':
        '5', '...--': '3',"":" "}


msg = ".... . .-.. .-.. -----  .-- --- .-. .-.. -.."

def is_morse(message):
    spl = message.split(" ")
    return  all(m in morse for m in spl)

if is_morse(msg):
    print("".join([morse[ch] for ch in msg.split(" ")]))
```

It is possible to parse it as a single string getting all variations, it just take a lot more work.

If you want to go the other way then you just reverse the mappings:

```
to_morse = {v: k for k, v in morse.items()}

def can_morse(msg):
    return all(ch in to_morse for ch in msg.upper())


msg = "Hello  World"
if can_morse(msg):
    print(" ".join([to_morse[ch] for ch in msg.upper()]))
```

I choose extra spaces to delimit the words, you can choose whatever you like just make sure to add the characters to the dict mapping then to a space or whatever you want the words delimited by.

Comment: why is the space character included?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, if the OP plans on parsing it back into english in a straightforward manner then the spaces are necessary

Comment: why *only* space then? If you want to combine tokenizing the input into letters and validation of individual letters then at least standard space should be allowed i.e., `letters = message.split()` and `is_morse = all(map(morse.__contains__, letters))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, how would you separate words if you `message.split()`?

Comment: there are many characters. Why do you need to separate words to check whether all letters are valid? The question of text segmentation at the level larger than a letter is off topic for the question (otherwise specify how would you encode punctuation, Unicode characters, extract sentences, paragraphs, etc)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I mean when joining , splitting on `" "` will keep spaces between words when using single spaces between letters and two or more between words. Just splitting msg will make the output `HELLOWORLD` as opposed to `HELLO WORLD`, the OP is free to choose whatever they like as a delimiter between words, I used  spaces as that was what I used originally

Comment: Thanks! I got this implemented with the DetectEnglish module, if a string contains ".- " then try to convert it into Morse Code and use the detect english module to see if it translate to english, it errors when trying to convert to morse code though, so i guess i'll have to do some try excepts! thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, the translating in the answer is at a very basic level, I just added it to show that having the allowed characters does not make the message valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any()`:

```
def is_morse(message):
    return bool(message) and not any(ch not in '.- ' for ch in message)
```

The `bool(message)` bit also rejects zero-length messages.

Comment: FYI: a solution based on `all()` would be much more readable than my solution. I just couldn't remember how to spell `all()` :)

Answer (score 3):

Check if each element of `message` is in the proper alphabet:

```
if all(c in ['-', '.'] for c in message):
```

or reduce the message to a set:

```
if set(message) <= set(['.', '-'])
```

or use a regular expression:

```
if re.match('[-.]*$', message):
```

Comment: You need a `^` anchor at the beginning of the regexp.

Comment: `match` applies the regex to the beginning of the string; `search` would require the `^`.

Comment: You can use `'-.'` instead of `['-', '.']`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple regular expression -

```
import re

def is_morse(message):
    return True if bool(re.match(r'^[.-]+$', message)) else False
```

This would be probably faster too, than iterating over the each character in message.

Comment: What about the space char?

Comment: I don't think space character is allowed.

Comment: Maybe it is like this. Then it would probably be better to name the funnction after it, for example `is_morse_letter` or `is_morse_symbol`...

Answer (score 0):

I guess most Pythonic would be to use a list comprehension here. This checks if a string consist purely out of - and . characters:

```
s = '---...---'
ismorse = all(c in ('-','.') for c in s)
```

Comment: That's a generator passed as an argument to `all`, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Would this meet your needs?

```
for char in message:
    if char not in '.-':
        return False
return True
```

Comment: This is just a reimplementation of `all`.